# How to include image in html email

Tags: html, wcf, smtp

In our WCF app, there is a method to send an html formatted email. I am using StringBuilder to build the html.

I am including an image in the email. When the app sends the email, the email is formatted correctly. However, the image doesn't display unless the user right clicks and selects "Download the Image".

Is there a way to have the image automatically display in the html email without the user having to select download image?

Here is my image tag:

```
<img src='http://www.MySite.com/Images/Mylogo.png' border='0' />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intentional behavior of the email client, there's no way to guarantee that the image will automatically show for all clients. You're going to have to live with that. In fact, some people prefer to read email in plain text.

If the image is relatively small, you might consider attaching it to the email instead. You'd have a better chance of having it displayed by default, though there are obviously other costs.